# Implement rake db:rollback STEP=n inside rakefile

Tags: ruby, rake, rollback, rake-task, rakefile

I'm trying to combine a bunch of rake tasks like this:

```
desc 'Resets the database'
task :reset do
  Rake::Task["db:rollback"].invoke
  Rake::Task["db:migrate"].invoke
  Rake::Task["db:seed"].invoke
end
```

I don't know how to do `rollback` with `STEP=n` inside my Rakefile

Comment: Why do you want a rake task like that? What do you try to archive? Should `n` be fixed or variable? Do you really always run `db:seed`, even if you for example only rolled back one step?

Comment: Because otherwise I have to run 3 rake commands to reset my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

STEP is an environment variable, so if you do this:

```
    desc 'Resets the database'
    task :reset do
      ENV['STEP'] = '1000' 
# The number has to be greater than
# or equal to the number of your migrations.

      Rake::Task["db:rollback"].invoke
      Rake::Task["db:migrate"].invoke
      Rake::Task["db:seed"].invoke
    end
```

that should work

Comment: Thanks a lot. `ENV['STEP'] = n` doesn't work for some reason. But I tried it with `ENV['STEP'] = '1000'` which works just fine